# User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Tags: kubernetes

I have just set up k8s, while i’m createting a secret :

```
 sudo kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

and it gives me this error :

```
error: failed to create secret Post "localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/…": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

when I tries to add :--server=https://192.168.1.2:6443

```
sudo kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson --server=https://192.168.1.2:6443
```

I got this error :

```
error: failed to create secret Post "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets?fieldManager=kubectl-create&fieldValidation=Strict": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

when I tries to add :--insecure-skip-tls-verify

```
sudo kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson --server=https://192.168.1.2:6443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify
```

it gives me this error :

```
error: failed to create secret secrets is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

k config view

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
    client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED
```

/root/.docker/config.json

```
test@k8s-ctrlr:~$ sudo cat /root/.docker/config.json
{
        "auths": {
                "harbor-regitry.fr": {
                        "auth": "eW91c31c2VmQSQxMjM="
                }
        }
```

could anyone help please ?

Comment: Are you able to execute the remaining commands without any error..? If you are facing error only while creating secrets, can you share that docker config json file

Comment: yes only with this cmd,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you are mixing running kubectl as your `user` and `root`.

Let me explain:

- You run commands with `sudo` which implies root user that is having it's *kubeconfig* in `/root/.kube/config`

  - It does not use kubeconfig of your user.
  - That's why you have `localhost:8080` errors in the `kubectl` output
- You run your `kubectl config view` from **non-root user** which is having kubeconfig in `/home/YOUR_USER/.kube/config`

There are a few solutions for this issue but the easiest way would be to pass `--kubeconfig=/PATH/TO/KUBECONFIG` argument to `kubectl` to override default root thingy.

Comment: so I need to run it without sudo ?

Comment: I run this cmd  and I got this:kubectl create secret generic regcred
--from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json
--type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
--kubeconfig=/home/labnum/.kube/config
secret/regcred created
-bash: --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json: No such file or directory
-bash: --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson: No such file or directory
-bash: --kubeconfig=/home/labnum/.kube/config: No such file or directory

Comment: you see the result is not a type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson : kubectl get secret regcred --output=yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-02-02T14:56:59Z"
  name: regcred
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "8835784"
  uid: 90b9dc10-bc0d-431c-b8c1-1217d516a600
type: Opaque

Comment: @Javauser in that case I'd follow the Kubernetes docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/ and create your secret as secret.yaml and then kubectl apply -f secret.yaml. If the type set is correct there it will for sure create dockerconfig :).

Comment: @Javauser also as for your command, the kubectl create secret TYPE is wrong. It should be `kubectl create secret docker-registry`.